# Use member methods in another class "generically"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do the following:
I have Person class in which I want to be able to use any kind of implementation of the abstract Animal class, so I want to be able to create multiple persons in the main method, with every one of these persons being able to use either dogs or cats, etc., and these persons should use the specific implementation of the doSomething() method from the particular dog, cat, etc.
The implementation right now is not working, I know, the compiler of course says, that an Animal can't use the doSomething() method (since its virtual).
How can I achieve what I'm trying to do here?

### person.h

```
#include <animal.h>

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    ~Person();
    Animal *ani;
};

Person::Person (Animal *pointer) 
{
  ani = new Animal ();
}

Person::SomeMethod ()
{
  ani->doSomething ();
}

Person::~Person ()
{
  delete ani;
}
```

---

### animal.h

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal();
    ~Animal();
    virtual void doSomething () = 0; 
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog();
    void doSomething ();
};

Dog::Dog ()
{
  std::cout << "I've been created!" << std::endl;
}

Dog::doSomething ()
{
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

### main.h

```
#include <animal.h>
#include <person.h>

int main()
{
    Dog *bowser;
    Person *will = new Person (bowser);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ani = new Animal ();` needs to be changed to the class you want, not the base class.

Comment: _"Animal doesn't have a doSomething() method (since its virtual)."_ Huh?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fixed that, sorry for the mix up

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, I know that it would be possible to do it that way, but in the Person class, I want to be able to use any kind of implemented Animal class, i.e. dogs, cats, etc.

Comment: Still wrong. Being "pure virtual" is the reason you can't call it, though actually you _can_ still give even those functions definitions.

Comment: @Buitenlander You can by having a pointer to an `Animal` like you already have.  You just can't assign to the pointer the address of a `Animal`.  You have to assign to it a address of a derived class.

Comment: Consider the ownership of the `Dog` or `Animal`. Does `main()` own it, or does the `Person` class own it? Right now that is not clear. You have `Person` creating an `Animal`, but yet a pointer to a `Dog` is being passed from main. Two options would make more sense; pass an `Animal` pointer from main, create a `Dog` in `Person`, or create a `Dog` in main and pass an `Animal` pointer to `Person` for assignment to a member only (no creation in `Person`).

Comment: So, in order for letting the person be "generic" and accept any kind of implementation of animal, I would have to create the object in the main class and then pass the pointer to the person, right? But the problem is that in my current design, the Animal class needs arguments / vectors that are created in the Person class, so I would have to rethink my design, right?

Comment: @flatmouse you were faster then me.

Comment: Try writing this example without `new` and it might make more sense. Only use `Dog dog;` for example then take an `Animal* bowser = &dog;` somewhere. You get the polymorphic behavior from a pointer to an `Animal` base class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of `Person` accepting any `Animal`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() = default;
    virtual ~Animal() {};
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Person
{
public:
    Person(Animal* pointer); 
    ~Person();

    void SomeMethod();
    Animal *ani;
};

Person::Person(Animal *pointer)
    : ani{pointer} // initialize from passed pointer
{
    //ani = new Animal(); //Person doesn't create/own an animal
}

void Person::SomeMethod()
{
    ani->doSomething();
}

Person::~Person()
{
    //delete ani; // Person doesn't own animal
}

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog() = default;
    void doSomething();
};

Dog::Dog()
{
    std::cout << "I've been created!" << std::endl;
}

void Dog::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Dog bowser; // no new here, RAII will take care of killing the Dog
    Dog* bowser_ptr = &bowser;
    Person will(bowser_ptr);
    will.SomeMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of `Person` owning a random `Animal`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <exception>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal() = default;
    virtual ~Animal() {}; // must be virtual!
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    Dog();
    ~Dog();
    void doSomething();
};


class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat();
    ~Cat();
    void doSomething();
};

Animal* get_random_animal()
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 2);
    switch(dis(gen)) {
        case 1:
            return new Dog;
        case 2:
            return new Cat;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error{"Not sure which animal."};
    }
}

class Person
{
public:
    Person(); 
    Person(Person&&) = delete; // person contains raw pointers, we must either delete or specify the move constructor
    Person(const Person&) = delete; // person contains raw pointers, we must either delete or specify the copy constructor
    Person& operator=(Person&&) = delete; // person contains raw pointers, we must either delete or specify the move assignment operator
    Person& operator=(const Person&) = delete; // person contains raw pointers, we must either delete or specify the copy assignment operator
    ~Person();

    void SomeMethod();
    Animal *ani;
};

Person::Person()
    : ani{get_random_animal()} // initialize with random animal
{

}

void Person::SomeMethod()
{
    ani->doSomething();
}

Person::~Person()
{
    delete ani; // Person does own animal
}


Dog::Dog()
{
    std::cout << "I've been created! Woof!" << std::endl;
}

Dog::~Dog()
{
    std::cout << "I've been destroyed! Woof!" << std::endl;
}

void Dog::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Woof" << std::endl;
}


Cat::Cat()
{
    std::cout << "I've been created! Meow!" << std::endl;
}

Cat::~Cat()
{
    std::cout << "I've been destroyed! Meow!" << std::endl;
}

void Cat::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "Meow" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Person will;
    will.SomeMethod();

    std::cout << "\n More people with animals: \n";
    std::vector<Person> people(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
I've been created! Meow!
Meow

 More people with animals:
I've been created! Woof!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Woof!
I've been created! Meow!
I've been created! Woof!
I've been created! Woof!
I've been destroyed! Woof!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Woof!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
I've been destroyed! Woof!
I've been destroyed! Woof!
I've been destroyed! Meow!
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is, that the objects would have to be created in main, but I have a lot of functionality in Person (which _should_ stay there) which is needed for the construction of an Animal object...

Comment: sorry, I can't do anything with this, you changed too many things in my design...